# spring integation and received date issue

Tags: java, imap, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I'm using the latest spring integration (4.1.5) javax.mail (1.4.7) libraries but looks like this issue is sitting there from the beginning.

I'm trying to get received date from mail server via IMAP protocol but SI always returns null. This is because of row 301 in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/4.1.x/spring-integration-mail/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/AbstractMailReceiver.java

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new IntegrationMimeMessage((MimeMessage) filteredMessages[i]);
```

So instead of let me get IMAPMessage instance it makes me to get MimeMessage that has stub for method getReceivedDate:

```
public Date getReceivedDate() throws MessagingException {
return null;    
}
```

I see that header contains not null element **Received** so the only option I see is to parse this header manually.

Is it correct behaviour of SI? Bug or feature?
And how to avoid manual parsing of received date header?

Comment: Crazy question, but did you try to cast down MimeMessage to IMAPMessage?

Comment: sure. (com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage)in.getPayload() - cannot cast 'org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage' to 'com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at the Sun code; it uses the `INTERNALDATE` fetch item to populate the `receivedDate` property...

Line 1194 in javamail 1.5.2...

```
else if (item instanceof INTERNALDATE)
    receivedDate = ((INTERNALDATE)item).getDate();
```

However, Spring does not expose this; I have created a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3744).

Answer (score 2):

The received date is available as the `internaldate` fetch item.

Parsing Received is a great deal of notfun, which is probably why the Spring developers haven't done it yet and why you'll hate doing it. See if `internaldate` will do.

Comment: Unfortunately, Spring doesn't expose the INTERNAL date either [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3744).

Comment: You can get it from the IMAPMessage object you already have. https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.html#getReceivedDate()

Comment: Or, wait. Maybe I misunderstand and you don't have that IMAPMessage object. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah - it's a bug; a new message is created from the old one but it's a plain `MimeMessage` instead of an `IMAPMessage` we need to keep a reference to the old one so we can delegate to its methods.